# Sign transaction by two parties

Tags: solidity

I have a particular function in solidity which basically adds a Certificate in a mapping when called. However for the certificate to be actually added on the blockchain, it needs to have been signed by both parties before adding it. What is the best way to do this please? At the moment I have it implemented without getting confirmation from the second party. I have read about web3 signatures but don't know if i should use those in this case. Upon the first party generating the transaction I will send a message via socket.io to the party which the transaction is aimed to. This party can then either sign it or not. If it is signed then I want to add the certificate to the blockchain.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: `At the moment I have it implemented without getting confirmation from the second party` - if you share this code, then you might get a much more accurate response (relevant to your needs).

Comment: Check Idex, 0x protocol, how they use `ecrecover` function to verify that the message has been signed in Ethereum wallet. You can use MetaMask etc. Web3.js wallets for signing.

Answer (score 0):

Two choices are:

1.
Peer A sends the data signed to peer B by any possible mean (websockets, email, etc). Peer B signs and sends it back. Peer A or B can then add the certificate.

2.
Peer A sends the data signed (probably there is no need to sign it, the transaction is signed). Your function start filling on the certificate and leave pending the confirmation from peer B. Peer B can then send the data with the signature (also probably the signature is not needed) to the contract, the function compare it with Peer A data and if those match then sets a flag indicating that the data has been verified by the Peers.

The last one will require gas from both parties and in the case that peer B does not want to sign (confirm), Peer A will lose his gas. The advantage of the second one is that the peers do not need to be online at the same time, each one can go to the contract whenever they want/can.

Hope this helps.